# Regression in R with categorical variables

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I'm trying to understand regression in R. I'm trying to solve an exercise wich has a 100 random male-female dataset like this:

```
sex     sbp      bmi
male     130     40.0
female   126     29.0
female   115     25.0
male     120     33.0
female   128     34.0
...
```

I want to get a numerical summary (0) plot the relation between sbp and bmi (1) and estimate beta1, beta2 and sigma parameters with R^2 (2). Then, check the goodness of the model (3) and get the confidence intervals (4)..

I think that sex is a categorical variable, so here it's my code:

```
as.numeric(framingham$sex) - 1
apply(framingham, 2, class)

#0
framingham$sex <- factor (framingham$sex)
levels (framingham$sex) <- c("female", "male")
resultadoNumerico <- compareGroups(~., data = framingham)
resumenNumerico <- createTable(resultadoNumerico)
resumenNumerico

# 1
framinghamMatrix <- data.matrix(framingham)
pairs(framinghamMatrix)
cor(framinghamMatrix)

#2
regre <- lm(sbp ~ bmi+sex, data = framingham)
regreSum <- summary(regre)
regreSum
# Sigma
regreSum$sigma
# Betas
regreSum$coefficients

#3
plot(framingham$bmi, framingham$sbp, xlab = "SBP", ylab = "BMI")
abline (regre)
```

But i think that im not doing things right... Could you help me? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I haven't run the code yet but could you say why you think you're doing it wrong?

Comment: Cause then I need to compare the men and women regression straight lines and the summary of the model gives only one: Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  79.0624    11.0716   7.141 1.71e-10 ***
bmi           1.9338     0.3965   4.877 4.21e-06 ***
sexfemale      3.0395     3.7731   0.806    0.422

Comment: You only get an estimate for one level of a 2-level factor because the other level is the reference level. If you had both you'd be falling into the "dummy variable trap" and the results would be meaningless. http://www.algosome.com/articles/dummy-variable-trap-regression.html

Comment: mmm well, i think i don't understand that... As I told, it's the first time I see this... :/

Comment: This is really more a question about statistical modeling. If you don't understand how regression works with categorical variables, it's probably better if you ask at [stats.se]. This isn't a programming question and certainly isn't unique to R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the relation between variables try a plot called pairs.panels from psych library. It gives the distributions , scatter plot and correlation coefficients.

```
library(psych)
pairs.panels(framingham)
```

The sex variable here is categorical hence convert it into factor and then provide as input to your linear regression model. By alphabetical order the first level in the factor becomes your reference level and hence in the summary of model you can see only levels other than the reference level (in this case female is base -reference level)

```
framingham$sex<-as.factor(framingham$sex)
```

Now create your linear model.

```
model <- lm(sbp ~ bmi+sex, data = framingham)
model
summary(model)
```

The summary gives the coefficients, intercept, standard error (95% confidence) , t-value and p-value( that indicates the significance of variables), Multiple R-squared (Goodness of fit) , Adjusted R-squared (Goodness of fit adjusted to model complexity) etc.

Comment: Yes but then... how can I compare the straight lines between males and females? And prediction? And contrasting hypothesis for beta1=1.75? I'm in a mess :(

Answer (score 0):

I've made sex-1 for the categorical variable:

```
regre <- lm(sbp ~ bmi+sex***-1***, data = framingham)
regreSum <- summary(regre)
regreSum
```

And now I obtain

```
Call:
lm(formula = sbp ~ bmi + sex - 1, data = framingham)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-28.684 -13.025  -1.314   8.711  73.476 

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
bmi         1.9338     0.3965   4.877 4.21e-06 ***
sexhombre  79.0624    11.0716   7.141 1.71e-10 ***
sexmujer   82.1020    10.5184   7.806 6.93e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 18.48 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9813,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9808 
F-statistic:  1700 on 3 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Maybe am I going in the right way?